# How can I assign a value to each anchor tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to insert multiple anchor tags inside `<form>`. How do I assign a value to each `<a>` so that I can use it on my Servlet called in the form and perform different tasks to each `<a>`?

Comment: use link like /api/getcategory?task="what you want" in anchor tag based on that task we can have case and do waht you want

Comment: @AshokKumarN I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. Can you explain it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider I need to do operations for 4 tasks based on the anchor tag

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
<a href="/ReportProcess?task=create">Task 1</a>
<a href="/ReportProcess?task=update">Task 2</a>
<a href="/ReportProcess?task=delete">Task 3</a>
<a href="/ReportProcess?task=edit">Task 4</a>
</form>
```

based on the anchor href as value and do according to it.
i need to have more clarity on what you need to perform

**Servlet part:**

consider the servlet URL is "/ReportProcess"

```
String task=req.getParameter("task");

switch(task)
{
 case "create":
 System.out.println("task create called");
 break;

 case "update":
 System.out.println("task update called");
 break;

 case "delete":
 System.out.println("task delete called");
 break;
}
```

Comment: so how can I use these on Servlet? I want to know on the servlet which anchor tag was clicked. Can I used this in request.getParameter(name)? If so, how?

Comment: @JewelynSee I update the answer as per the comments

Comment: So if my Servlet url is ReportProcess, I just have to write /ReportProcess?task=1  ?

Comment: There's a type mismatch in Integer task = request.getParameter("task"), should I typecast it to Integer or do I have to use parseInt? Last question, what does n refer to in the switch cases? Should I just declare n as int and not assign it to anything? Sorry for many questions.. Thank you again, I'll accept your answer as soon as it works!

Comment: actually for understanding, I gave you the number, always use the task name for understanding, readability and have a string datatype in switch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204116/discussion-between-jewelyn-see-and-ashok-kumar-n).